# How to write to event log with critical level using nlog?

Tags: logging, event-log, nlog

I'm trying to write log from nlog to window's event log. This is my configuration

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
    <targets>                
        <target name="eventLog" xsi:type="EventLog" layout="${longdate} [${level:upperCase=true}] : ${message} ${exception:format=ToString}" log="Application" source="mySource"/>
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="eventLog"/>
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

I need to distinguish logs in event log by their levels, I need to have separate `Error` and `Critical` level logs
but those lines:

```
logger.Error("error test do eventLogu");
logger.Fatal("fatal test do eventLogu");
```

both write to event log with `Error` level.

Is it possible to write log with Critical level using nlog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't look like it.

If my understanding is correct, the EventLogTarget uses the [EventLogEntryType Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogentrytype.aspx) to choose the event log level.  This enumeration does not have a value for critical, which is used for lower level (kernel, etc) events.

The [NLog Code](https://github.com/jkowalski/NLog/blob/master/src/NLog/Targets/EventLogTarget.cs) itself  says

```
else if (logEvent.Level >= LogLevel.Error)
{
    entryType = EventLogEntryType.Error;
}
```

Joe